Parsing data in Bash: adding commas after each string
I am attempting to generate a file that I can append to visudo. The task itself is not too important as I'm just trying to dig a little deeper Bash. My current script looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

path=/bin/ansible*
declare -a commands=()

for command in $path; do
        commands+=($command)
done

echo ${commands[@]} > ~/commands.txt

which outputs:
/bin/ansible /bin/ansible-config /bin/ansible-connection /bin/ansible-console...

I'd like the output of the script to look like:
/bin/ansible, /bin/ansible-config, /bin/ansible-connection, /bin/ansible-console...

I think I am over complicating this task. I've seen folks use awk and sed, but from what I have seen awk seems to work better with columns of data and sed is just very confusing. Any advice would be appreciated.

printf '%s\n' "${commands[@]}" | paste -sd ','

Don't expand a wildcard that might return multiple values into a scalar string. Use an array as you have done elsewhere.
In the naïve case where you're outputting a string value with a comma after it, you can do this:
shopt -s nullglob          # Replace non-matches with an empty string
paths=(/bin/ansible*)      # All matching items (or none)
shopt -u nullglob          # Unless you had already set it earlier

echo "${paths[@]/%/, }"    # Each element with a comma after it

However, for the realistic case where the comma is a separator rather than a terminator you need to strip it off the last element. This approach avoids using a loop:
shopt -s nullglob                        # Replace non-matches with an empty string
paths=(/bin/ansible*)                    # All matching items (or none)
shopt -u nullglob                        # Unless you had already set it earlier

delimiteds=("${paths[@]/%/, }")          # Append comma+space to all elements
delimiteds[-1]="${delimiteds[-1]%, }"    # Remove last element's comma+space
echo "${delimiteds[@]}"

A couple of notes,

The shopt nullglob option ensures that if a wildcard is used that has no matches the result will be the empty string rather than the original pattern match including the wildcards as literal characters (try echo bin/ansible* and then echo bin/rhubarb*; notice the second one returns the original string including the * character)
I've used echo as a quick way to output the array elements. Beware using it for values that start with - (or in some cases that contain escape sequences such as \r or \n)


Why should we use shopt in this context? The other answers use shopt as well, but I'm not too sure what it does. Is it commonly used when working with data like this, or is it used because of how I tried to retrieve the data?

@Ambre The particular shell option that this answer enables with shopt is the nullglob option. Enabling this ensures that a pattern that does not match anything is removed. Ordinarily, patterns that don’t match anything are left unexpanded.

@Ambre I've amended my answer to explain what the shopt nullglob does, and an example of why you'd want it

Try zsh instead which has a builtin operator to join the elements of an array with an arbitrary strings.
#! /bin/zsh -
ansible_commands=( /bin/ansible*(N) )
print -r -- ${(j[, ])ansible_commands} > ~/commands.txt

Or without the intermediary variable, using an anonymous function:
#! /bin/zsh -
function {
  print -r -- ${(j[, ])@}
} /bin/ansible*(N) > ~/commands.txt

In bash, the only builtin joining operator is the Korn-style "${array[*]}" which joins the elements of an array with the first character of $IFS but none to join with strings of more than one character such as ", " here.
It doesn't have zsh's N qualifier and hasn't copied ksh's ~(N) yet, even with shopt -s extglob, so you need to set the nullglob option globally for globs with no-match to expand to nothing.
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob
ansible_commands=( /bin/ansible* )
{
  printf %s "${ansible_commands[0]}"
  [ "${#ansible_commands[@]}" -le 1 ] ||
    printf ', %s' "${ansible_commands[@]:1}"
  printf '\n'
} > ~/commands.txt

Or use perl for instance (in any shell, even bash, though you might as well use sh which is guaranteed to be found on any system):
#! /bin/sh -
perl -le 'print join ", ", </bin/ansible*>' > ~/commands.txt


Looking over the answers I realize how ignorant I actually am. I noticed almost everyone used the "shopt" command, could you help me understand why we use shopt?

@Ambre, see edit.


I think I am over complicating this task

You could say that. Using globbing as in /bin/ansible* already gives you an array. You don't have to coppy elements from that array into another array!
So, you can directly
printf '%s, ' /bin/ansible* > ~/commands.txt
printf '\n' > ~/commands.txt

That's it.
That is, if you want to ignore the fact that you will fail when there's no matching file, and you will have a trailing ,  anyways.
If you want to fix both issues:
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s, ' /bin/ansible* | sed 's/, $/\n/'> ~/commands.txt


Beware \n in the replacement is a GNUism. The output of printf is also not valid text as it's missing the trailing newline, so what sed does on that output is unspecified and in practice varies with the implementation. Files in /bin are unlikely to have newlines in their name, but still for correctness, you'd want to do that substitution on the last line only

Why make it f-difficult ,try this :
for i in ${commands[@]} ; do echo -n "${i},"; done; echo
Can remove the last "," with sed
